# Convert json string to php associative array

Tags: php, json

No idea why this won't convert, I would assume it may have something to do with the string, but I get np output.

```
$string = '[{title : "Comp 1 Product",columns : ["Our Vehicle","Features","Their Vehicle"], items : [["dcq","adv","asdvasdv"],["sdv","sdv","sdv"]]},{title : "qwefqw",columns : ["Section 1","Features","Section 2"],items : [["qqwec","qwe","qwegqwev"]]}]';

print_r(json_decode($string), true);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's not valid JSON. In JSON, property names need to be in double quotes.

Comment: Where did that string come from? You need to fix the source so that it creates the JSON properly. It should use a JSON library instead of constructing it by hand.

Comment: I have posted the way to debug such problems and identify what the problem is. Please correct at the source.

Comment: Also, give the `true` to the left of bracket. i.e., `print_r(json_decode($string, true));`

Comment: Do you wanna accept any of the answers?

Comment: The reason I didn't suspect the source is that handlebar.js accepts that string the way it is.

Comment: @GregAlexander JS and JSON are two different animals from the same mother... `:D`

Answer (score 6):

If you see:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/plain");
    $string = '[{title : "Comp 1 Product",columns : ["Our Vehicle","Features","Their Vehicle"], items : [["dcq","adv","asdvasdv"],["sdv","sdv","sdv"]]},{title : "qwefqw",columns : ["Section 1","Features","Section 2"],items : [["qqwec","qwe","qwegqwev"]]}]';
    print_r(json_decode($string), true);
    print_r(json_last_error());
?>
```

The above code returns a `4`, which means `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX`, which is a syntax error with JSON. When checked with JSON Lint, your JSON throws:

[image: prevoew]

You need to correct it to look like:

```
[{
    "title": "Comp 1 Product",
    "columns": ["Our Vehicle", "Features", "Their Vehicle"],
    "items": [
        ["dcq", "adv", "asdvasdv"],
        ["sdv", "sdv", "sdv"]
    ]
}, {
    "title": "qwefqw",
    "columns": ["Section 1", "Features", "Section 2"],
    "items": [
        ["qqwec", "qwe", "qwegqwev"]
    ]
}]
```

What you have now is a **JavaScript Object** and not a **valid JSON**!

Comment: I was about to post this :) +1

Comment: @Farkie Thanks mate... `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Apart from invalid json, `print_r(json_decode($string), true);` prints nothing, but returns the value. To get the result printed to the output, you need to either:

```
print_r(json_decode($string));
```

or

```
echo print_r(json_decode($string), true);
```

The former is better.